# Correctly migrate from Python 2 md5 library to Python 3 hashlib

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ccavenue

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party payment gateway (`CCAvenue`) in Django 1.11, Python 3.5.2

The reference code provided by the 3rd party uses the deprecated library md5 to encrypt texts.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import md5

def pad(data):
    length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
    data += chr(length)*length
    return data

def encrypt(plainText,workingKey):
    iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
    plainText = pad(plainText)
    encDigest = md5.new ()
    encDigest.update(workingKey)
    enc_cipher = AES.new(encDigest.digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    encryptedText = enc_cipher.encrypt(plainText).encode('hex')
    return encryptedText
```

How do I make the above `encrypt()` method Python 3 compatible using the `hashlib` library of Python 3? Can you post the whole method?

Comment: Your mean Python 2 to 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING: Don't use crypto or pycrypto anymore!** [read more](https://blog.sqreen.com/stop-using-pycrypto-use-pycryptodome/)

Here's a Python 3 compatible way of doing the same:

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from hashlib import md5

from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes

iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
# for python 3.9 & pycryptodome, this need to be byte
iv = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'

BS = 16


def _pad(data):
    return data + (BS - len(data) % BS) * chr(BS - len(data) % BS)


def _unpad(data):
    return data[0:-ord(data[-1])]


def encrypt(plain_text, working_key):
    plain_text = _pad(plain_text)
    enc_cipher = AES.new(md5(force_bytes(working_key)).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, _iv)
    return hexlify(enc_cipher.encrypt(plain_text)).decode('utf-8')


def decrypt(cipher_text, working_key):
    encrypted_text = unhexlify(cipher_text)
    dec_cipher = AES.new(md5(force_bytes(working_key)).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, _iv)
    return _unpad(dec_cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Works perfectly @ashwini. CCAvenue should update their reference code with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for  python3.8 and Django 3.2 pycryptodome==3.17

```
 from Crypto.Cipher import AES
 import hashlib
 from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def pad(data):
    length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
    data += chr(length)*length
    return data

def unpad(data):
    return data[0:-ord(data[-1])]

def encrypt(plainText, workingKey):
    iv =b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
    plainText = pad(plainText)
    bytearrayWorkingKey = bytearray()
    bytearrayWorkingKey.extend(map(ord, workingKey))
    enc_cipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(bytearrayWorkingKey).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return hexlify(enc_cipher.encrypt(plainText.encode('utf-8'))).decode('utf-8')

def decrypt(cipherText, workingKey):
    iv = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
    encryptedText = unhexlify(cipherText)
    bytearrayWorkingKey = bytearray()
    bytearrayWorkingKey.extend(map(ord, workingKey))
    decCipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(bytearrayWorkingKey).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(decCipher.decrypt(encryptedText).decode('utf-8'))`
```