# Correctly migrate from Python 2 md5 library to Python 3 hashlib in Flask web application for CCAvenue integration

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, hashlib, ccavenue

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party payment gateway (**CCAvenue**) in Flask 0.12.2, Python 3.6.1.

The reference code provided by the 3rd party uses the deprecated library **md5** to encrypt texts.

I have got the solution for migration in [Existing Solution in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44992024). However, I need Flask version code for the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rahul08M/5c5399bb3d42cba5f53784dab47e5bb0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution and here is the code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def pad(data):
    length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
    data += chr(length)*length
    return data

def unpad(data):
    return data[0:-ord(data[-1])] 

def encrypt(plainText, workingKey):
    iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
    plainText = pad(plainText)
    bytearrayWorkingKey = bytearray()
    bytearrayWorkingKey.extend(map(ord, workingKey))
    enc_cipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(bytearrayWorkingKey).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return hexlify(enc_cipher.encrypt(plainText)).decode('utf-8')

def decrypt(cipherText, workingKey):
    iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
    encryptedText = unhexlify(cipherText)
    bytearrayWorkingKey = bytearray()
    bytearrayWorkingKey.extend(map(ord, workingKey))
    decCipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(bytearrayWorkingKey).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(decCipher.decrypt(encryptedText).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rahul08M/5c5399bb3d42cba5f53784dab47e5bb0

Comment: I am tried your answer. I got error " TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code  " . Can you assist me ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an update to @prash's solution which worked for me.
`iv was of type str`

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def pad(data):
    length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
    data += chr(length)*length
    return data

def unpad(data):
    return data[0:-ord(data[-1])] 

def encrypt(plainText, workingKey):
    iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'.encode("utf-8")
    plainText = pad(plainText)
    bytearrayWorkingKey = bytearray()
    bytearrayWorkingKey.extend(map(ord, workingKey))
    enc_cipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(bytearrayWorkingKey).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return hexlify(enc_cipher.encrypt(plainText.encode("utf-8"))).decode('utf-8')

def decrypt(cipherText, workingKey):
    iv = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
    encryptedText = unhexlify(cipherText)
    bytearrayWorkingKey = bytearray()
    bytearrayWorkingKey.extend(map(ord, workingKey))
    decCipher = AES.new(hashlib.md5(bytearrayWorkingKey).digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(decCipher.decrypt(encryptedText).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much .You save my time.  I am tried 5 hours after I got your answer.